# CSS Text Wrapping issue and HTML setup of cohosts

Tags: html, css, word-wrap

Ok, I have HTML setup like so:

```
<div class="bullet">
    <div style="float: left; padding-right: 1em;">
        <img src="images/ofn_bullet.png" alt="OFN" style="max-width: 100%; border: none;" />
    </div>
    <div style="float: left;">
        Cooperative Business Assistance Corporation<br />Camden, NJ
    </div>
    <br class="clear" />
</div>
```

There are a ton of these, listed on this page here:  http://opportunityfinance.net/Test/2013conf/index.html  They get listed 1 after the other, because, unfortunately I don't know how else to do this.  Is there an easier way to do this for each Co-Host??  I've tried using a `<ul>` tag with the `list-type-image` being set, and having `<li>` tags for this (which was my first attempt), but I couldn't figure out how to get the image to resize as the page was resized, so I scrapped that attempt, and went with the following attempt above.  But am now having other issues.  Basically, both of these `div` tags have a `float: left` style which should work, however if you look at the pic below... doesn't work right when sizing it down:

[image: Text Wrapping to next line down instead of staying on right-side of image]

Honestly, I don't know what to do, and I don't want to use a table.  But I do need to align the text next to it so that it is in the middle of the image, if possible.  Like the 2 lines should be `vertically aligned` in the `middle` `vertical-align: middle`, if possible.  In any case, I need the text to stay on the right-hand side of the image at all times, even when the browser is resized down!  Here is the CSS for what is being used:

```
.clear
{
    clear: both;
}

div.bullet
{
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
}
```

I'm wondering if there is a better setup solution for the Co-Hosts column, than what I am using.  Keep in mind that the page needs to resize down (text and all) for smaller screen resolutions and cell phones.  Can't have a horizontal scrollbar either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have the cohosts as an unordered list. You could then set the image as a background image for each list item.

```
<ul class='cohosts'>
    <li>The text</li>
    <li>The text</li>
</ul>
```

Then set the css to something like this

```
.cohosts li {
    padding-left: 20px; /* Whatever the with of the image */
    background-image: url('images/ofn_bullet.png');
}
```

Comment: You can set a `background-image` for `<li>` tags?  Didn't know this.  Thought you can only do that on regular elements, and that `ul` tags should use the `list-type-image` instead.  Curious, is there a way to set a `max-width` for the image this way?  Or if we can set the width and height of the image, that might be fine also.

Comment: Have a look into css 'backgound-size'. I don't know it too well myself but it may be what you need here.

Comment: Decided to go with this approach.  Thanks.  I'm setting the `background-size` via jQuery, however, only works in IE9+ and latest versions of other browsers because of it being a `CSS3` property.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing `float: left;` on `.bullet` (the text div)

Comment: Thanks, this actually worked, but am waiting for, perhaps a better solution to the HTML Repition that I'm facing using `div` tags for this.  I'm wondering if there is a way to do it with `ul` tags and resize the `background-image` proportionally as I'm doing with the rest of the images when the browser gets resized down.